# Reduce overlapping / close polylines to one line

Tags: qgis, merge

I have a shapefile with multiple (often not perfectly overlapping lines). Attached is a picture of a typical situation found in the shapefile. I would like my output to have only one line (attributes are not important). 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `dissolve`?

Comment: Have you tried GRASS tool (under QGIS) `v.clean` with clean tool `snap` and a threshold in layer unit for snapping object within this threshold ? And after do a `dissolve` ?

Comment: The search term "conflation" might help you research this topic.

Comment: @J.Monticolo: I tried using v.clean, but I struggle to find the right settings (threshold, snap). How do you find thresholds and snap tolerance?

Comment: Snap tool in the clean tool, threshold by observation and knowing your data.